# How to get past stalled initial station search in NextRadio?

Tags: applications, fm-radio

I have a phone with an FM chip. To make use of it, I installed [NextRadio](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nextradioapp.nextradio). During onboarding, NextRadio is supposed to look up local radio stations. However, it hangs on this step, displaying a throbber but going no further and not responding to any input. How can I get past this step so I can use the app?

Answer (score 0):

With data networks (cellular data, Wi-Fi) disabled, NextRadio's station search will fail immediately instead of hanging.

Try enabling airplane mode, then re-opening NextRadio. Instead of stalling and showing the activity indicator, it should give you a message that it couldn't find a station listing. Tap "OK" to proceed.

Now disable airplane mode, as it also disables the radio. Using the basic tuner, you can add stations as favorites to assign a name to them.